# Learning python... stumped. Where is the loop in this function?

Tags: python, loops

I do not understand how the result is 10...
Specifically where in the function does it create the loop that adds 1, 2, 3 and 4?

I am also new to Stackoverflow, so if there is a relative article that I overlooked then please do refer me.

```
def func(x):
    res=0
    for i in range(x):
        res += i
    return res

print(func(5))
```

Comment: Do you know what [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) does in Python?

Comment: "Where is the loop in this function?"--> `for i in range(x)` <-- here it is

Comment: Isn't `for` telling you that it's a loop already? Which language are you from anyway?

Comment: you are doing the equivalent of  `0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 `, which results in 10. Not exactly rocket science, but it's good that you are learning :D

Comment: `range(5)` will generate `[0,1,2,3,4]` so you are doing `0+1+2+3+4`,so it will result `10`

Comment: I'd highly recommend checking out [the wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func(x):             # defines the function name and input parameter
    res=0                # created a variable that is right now set to 0
    for i in range(x):   # this has two parts, for-loop, and a range function both explained below
        res += i         # this adds 1 to the variable 'res' each time the for-loop loops
    return res           # end of the function, passes the variables value back to the caller

print(func(5))           # call the function while passing 5 as an argument
```

This is how a for loop works,

it will loop over each element you provide it.

so,

```
myPets = ['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit']    # create a list of pets
for pet in myPets:
    print pet                  # print each pet
```

When this runs, you get

```
dog
cat
rabbit
```

Now the `range` function, creates a sequence of x numbers ranging from 0 to x-1 so,

```
range(5)
```

is equivalent to:

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

Keep in mind, it starts at 0 and ends at x-1

we could also do

```
range(3, 6)
```

which would be equivalent to:

```
[3,4,5]
```

note that in python2 `range` actually returns the list where as in python3 `range` is a separate sequence type. For the purposes of a for loop, they do the same thing.

Comment: you need quotes around your pets: `['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit']` and `range` doesn't "give us" a list in python 3, it is **equivalent** to the list.

Comment: OP did not specify 2 or 3. So I assumed 2. I'll add a note to the answer regardless. Thanks

Comment: I assumed vs3 because of the call to the `print()` function.

Comment: I see. I didn't notice that before.

Comment: [you were not the only one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002457/learning-python-stumped-where-is-the-loop-in-this-function/36002571?noredirect=1#comment59657503_36002509) I really like your line-by-line commenting the function as an opening to the answer, although you could add "explained below" to the `for` line.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Seeing it in a different light with the dog, cat, rabbit part is where it finally clicked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you need to know what does the [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function to understand that loop.

`range(x)` function creates an array which contains from 0 to x-1. So `range(5)` create the array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. So the loop:

```
for i in range(5)
```

it's equivalent to:

```
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: technically speaking `range` it is its own sequence type in python3 which the OP is probably using based on the call to `print()` but it does act the same way as a **list** (other then not supporting item assignment and executing way faster)

Answer (score 0):

From [Python.org](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html):

> If you do need to iterate over a sequence of numbers, the built-in function `range()` comes in handy. It generates lists containing arithmetic progressions, e.g.:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Essentially, `for i in range(10)` is the same as saying `for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

The `+=` operator is the same as saying `res = res + value`

So, in combination with the range statement, this piece of code is looking at the first element of the list, `0`, adding that to zero(your starting element: `res = 0`), then adding one to that, then adding two to the result of the previous computation (resulting in `3`), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(x):
```

This is the loop you are looking for. It iterates over every element in `range(x)`.

When you have `range(5)`, you are telling python to generate 5 integers, which are up to but not including 5. So they are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

The `+=` operator adds right operand to the left operand and assign the result to left operand.

So in your case, with the function and the loop iterating from 0 to 4, you are telling python to generate a function called `func(x)`; within this function, generate a range of integers, from 0 up to but not including 5; add whatever i is to res (to add 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 sequentially to res).

Finally it becomes 10.

Answer (score 0):

`res += i` means `res= res+i` 
so for loop loops as below
`res = 0`, initially 
The supplied list for looping is

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

so `res += i` is applied for each element of the list
the variable 'i' is a temporary variable used to loop through the for loop function.
so value of 'i' will be changing every time it loops i.e

```
i=0
i=1
i=2
i=3
i=4
```

the value of res keeps on changing as per the for loop

```
res= 0+0 =0
res= 0+1 =1
res= 1+2 =3
res= 3+3 =6
res= 6+4 =10
```

Final returned value is 10 as for loop ends at 4 value in the list

Comment: Thank you for this comment! I was having difficulty understanding how it looped until I read this.

Comment: Thankyou Tucker. I am very happy that my comment helped you.